# Load Only Part of an Ember App at Once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am building an ember app and it is starting to get large.  Is there any way to do lazy loading of the ember files so that it does take 10+ seconds to load when the user first hits the site?  For example since I have several logically separate modules as part of the site, I could load the modules as they are accessed.  I am using ruby on rails and the ember-rails gem.

Comment: What's taking 10+ seconds?  Are you bundling your js files, minimizing?  Using prod ember?

Comment: Ok to be fair this is in development:)  The point is that even in production it will still be 3-4 seconds because I have dozens of beefy html files

Comment: Are you pre-compiling your templates also?  You can definitely lazy load things, but generally this just leads to slower times and complexity within the app.  Most people prefer the one time load, then it's a SPA, at that point everything moves around like butter.  Gmail is a good example of this, a few seconds to load easily, then like magic.

Comment: likewise, if you have a landing page, you could separate out a base set of necessary js files, then lazily load the others later.  Which particular files would you like to lazy load?

Comment: Basically I have a landing page where the user will get to choose one of 3 portions of the site.  The 3 portions are completely separate.  So it would be logical to only load one portion at a time.  I am using rails btw as my backend and the ember-rails gem

Comment: Ok I think I have a solution.  I'll just create 3 separate ember namespaces(apps) and load each of them on separate urls accessed from the landing page.

Comment: do it to it, we have a similar structure, thought we have a core set of shared functionality, then we load a separate bundle for completely different apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what Ember is actually doing to render that code, you can understand why it is slow. Suppose you're creating 2k view instances, and rendering 2k templates. Templates that for the most part are doing very little. Especially if you don't care about data binding.

For a first stab, let's stop rendering through templates. This code uses `itemViewClass` to render each item with a custom view instead of the view used internally by `each`.

```
// Use with {{each item in items itemViewClass=App.SpanView}}
App.SpanView = Em.View.extend({
  render: function(buffer) {
    buffer.push("<span>"+this.get('content')+"</span>\n");
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/enapec/35/edit66

With render over-ridden, we need to interact with the render buffer ourselves.

Even faster would be getting rid of the view entirely. I think there are two ways to do this. You could create a custom view with a `render` method that loops over all the items, and pushes each element onto the buffer. I think given the previous example you can get that going yourself.

Another simple option is to use a helper. A dumb helper like this is more difficult to wire up for re-rendering when the list changes, but sometimes it is the right solution.

```
// Use with {{eachInSpan items}}
Em.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('eachInSpan', function (items) {
  return (
    new Handlebars.SafeString(
      items.map(function (i) {
        return '<span>'+i+'</span>';
      })
    )
  );
});
```

Live JSBin: http://jsbin.com/enapec/34/edit

Lastly, you could do this in jQuery with `didInsertElement` and the `afterRender` queue. I don't recommend it though.

`Ember.RenderBuffer` gathers information regarding the a view and generates the final representation. `Ember.RenderBuffer` will generate HTML which can be pushed to the DOM.

FYI here is the **[RenderBuffer API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RenderBuffer.html)**

**[DEFINED IN](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-views/lib/system/render_buffer.js#L78)**

**MODULE** : **[Ember-views](http://emberjs.com/api/modules/ember-views.html)**

I am also new bee but I got this from some resource. Thanks.

Comment: There's so much other low hanging fruit, the extra work to create and maintain your own rolled rendering schema is doubtfully cost effective.  Fun stuff, but probably not worth it.

Comment: @kingpin2k : may be you are right but I am not aware about those other low hanging fruits. I would like to know the other ways also as I am learning day by day new things and I love to find out easy way. Thanks

Comment: minimization, bundling, precompiling templates, unbound template properties, using the prod version of ember (instead of debug version), all of these are awesome steps when you are facing performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

On this Keynote on Embercamp London 2016, @wycats and @tomdale talk about the plans for improving Ember with slicing and dicing of the app. They talk about loading only what it's needed for that particular route. This is going to be great. I think that's what you wanted :)

https://www.periscope.tv/w/1mrGmzPBvQqJy#